# windows installer error when specifying "setupIcon"

Tags: electron

I've already packaged the app correctly and am now going through the whole `electron-winstaller` processs, following the Christian Engvall tutorial exactly.

In `createInstaller.js` I have the standard

```
return Promise.resolve({
    appDirectory: path.join(outPath, '/MyApp-win32-x64/'),
    authors: 'Me',
    noMsi: true,
    outputDirectory: path.join(outPath, 'windows-installer'),
    exe: 'MyApp.exe',
    setupExe: 'Setup.exe',
    setupIcon: path.join(rootPath, '/path/to/appicon.ico')
});
```

If I remove the `setupIcon` parameter, it builds the installer just fine. However if I keep it there, I get an 'Unable to load file' error from the console. I've verified that the path to the .ico file is in fact correct, and is a valid .ico file.

What could possibly be happening?

Comment: For who still got stuck in this case, see the EDIT part of https://github.com/electron/forge/issues/1635#issuecomment-695370197

Answer (score -1):

To fix the Setup Icon error when creating an installer with `electron-wininstaller` you can use `Resource Hacker`.

It is for editing the `exe` file and you can change the ressource file and icons.

For more information you there is a tutorial [here](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker).